# How do I echo/print the amount of times I am looping a "do until" loop in command prompt in VBS?

Tags: loops, printing, vbscript, echo

Basically I am trying to print the "Do Until" number in this example to the command prompt. How do I do this? Here is my loop code:

```
'LOOP START
Dim x
x=0
Do Until x=5
(loop contents)
x=x+1
Loop
'LOOP END
```

Comment: `wscript.echo x` inside the loop. Run the script with `cscript scriptname.vbs`

Comment: unfortunately that would just give me "0", but I am looking for it to say "5" in this example since that is the maximum amount of loops. Would you know how to do that? That is why it is tricky (for me at least) since it is "do until" and not the actual value of X (no idea how to echo that)

Comment: @LesFerch (above)

Comment: Please see the answer I've posted.

Answer (score 1):

With the trivial example provided, the answer is also trivial. That is, you know that the loop will execute 5 times, so you can just display `5`, like so:

```
WScript.echo "5"
Do Until x=5
  x = x + 1
Loop
```

Presumably, the actual code your working with is more complex, but there's still really only two possibilities: 1) You know how may times the loop is going to execute (as in the example), or 2) you don't know because the loop is going to run until some condition is met. For example, a loop that checks every half second for a certain file to exist, could run any number of times.

Please post an example that more closely matches your actual code and then we can see if that leads to a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Sorry if I lacked clarification in my question. I am not trying to see the value of X as it is incremented or the final value of X. I am looking to print the amount of loops that will occur PRIOR to executing the loop. So I wanted to basically echo the number next to "Do Until" in command prompt PRIOR to running the loop / not after. I cannot seem to figure out how @LesFerch

Comment: I see that you asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72536037/15764378) and pretty much made no progress. This is an indication that we really can't make much sense of your question and it's time to try something different. I suggest asking a question that outlines what you are trying to accomplish, shows what you have done so far, and asks for some guidance. There's probably a simple solution, but we can't provide it without knowing what it is you trying to solve.